# WPF and PSD - how to import graphics

Tags: wpf, psd

I'm a developer of WPF application and I should to apply a design of application, created by designed in PSD format. But I even can't imagine what should I do at first time. How to import some element from PSD to my application? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Expression Blend supports importing PSDs](http://expressioniq.com/?p=965).